# not accepting variable within Jquery .html()

Tags: jquery

I have the code below that works, but I need to expand it, so I am attempting to make it more streamlined.

```
success: function setData(data) {
            $("#price" + lastchar).html(data.price);
            $("#matricule" + lastchar).html(data.matricule);
            $("#tag" + lastchar).html(data.tag);
            $("#ins_yr1" + lastchar).html(data.ins_yr1);
            $("#Totalacq" + lastchar).html(data.Totalacq);
        }
```

Like this:

```
success: function (data){
  var desc=[];
  desc = ["price","matricule","tag","ins_yr1","Totalacq"];
  for (var i=0;i<desc.length;i++){
    $( "#" + desc[i] + lastchar).html(data.desc[i]);
  }
}
```

But this does not work because it does not accept a variable `desc[i]` within the `.html()`, at least not in the format I am trying to do it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in `html`, but in the way you're trying to access `data` properties. But you can get/set them using `[]`, just like array indices:

```
data[desc[i]]
```

In other words, `data.price` is equivalent to `data["price"]`.

Comment: I realized I could make it even shorter by referencing the keys of the data file as below:    success: function (data){
   var keys=[];
   keys = Object.keys(data);
 for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
 $( "#" + keys[i] + lastchar).html(data[keys[i]]);
 }
 }

Answer (score 1):

Just lo leave that as reference for future use, I realized I could make it even shorter, by referencing directly the keys of the array object.

```
success: function (data){

    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
        $( "#" + keys[i] + lastchar).html(data[keys[i]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need `var keys = []` and then `keys = Object.keys(data)`, just go straight to `var keys = Object.keys(data)`.